# The $p=\infty$ case for an $L^2$ convolution operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Let $T$ be a convolution operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, suppose $K$ is a tempered distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that coincides with a locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$. Suppose that $K$ satisfies
$$
\int_{|x|>2|y|}|K(x-y)-K(x)|dx\leq B,~y\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$ 
for a constant $B$ (this is called the Hörmander condition and is a smoothness condition). Then for $1<r<\infty$ and $1<p<\infty$, we have the boundedness estimate
$$
\left|\left|  \left(\sum_{j}|Tf_j|^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}  \right|\right|_p
\leq C_{p,r} \left|\left|  \left(\sum_j|f_j|^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}    \right|\right|_p.
$$
For $p=1$, we have the estimate
$$
\left| \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\left(\sum_j|Tf_j(x)|^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}>\lambda  \} \right|
\leq \frac{C_r}{\lambda} \left|\left|  \left( \sum_j|f_j|^r \right)^{\frac{1}{r}}  \right|\right|_1.
$$
(This is a weak-type $(1,1)$ inequality).

My question is why do we not have a similar inequality for $p=\infty?$

A similar example is that we do not have $L^{\infty}-$boundedness for the Hilbert transform and a counterexample can be provided via step functions.

Does anyone know of a counterexample why $L^{\infty}-$boundedness does not exist? What is the intuitive reason behind it?

Comment: Haven't you answered your question by pointing out that the Hilbert transform doesn't map $L^{\infty}$ into $L^{\infty}$, and more generally singular integrals don't either? If you take the sequence $\left\{f_{j}\right\}\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\ell^{r})$ consisting of the characteristic functions of pairwise disjoint intervals and take $T$ to be the Hilbert transform, then $(\sum_{j}\left|Tf_{j}\right|^{r})^{1/r}\geq \left|Tf_{1}\right|\notin L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know that singular integrals do not map $L^{\infty}$ to $L^{\infty}$, but I was wondering what the non-rigorous intuition was on it. For example, when dealing with restriction and Strichartz estimates, $L^{\infty}$ is considered optimal/best control. So why would someone intuitively think that you could not map $L^{\infty}$ to $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your question then. Based on your reply comment, it seems you're asking why singular integrals intuitively don't map $L^{\infty}$ into $L^{\infty}$. If this is your question, I don't see why you have to frame it in the vector-valued setting. Also, unless a bounded linear operator $T:L^{\infty}\rightarrow L^{\infty}$ is a positive operator on measurable functions, I don't believe it a priori has a bounded linear extension to $\tilde{T}: L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\ell^{r})\rightarrow L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\ell^{r})$.